# jQuery Calorie Calculator Conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, conditional-statements

I'm building a Calorie Calculator and would like to ask for some help. Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ingredient').click(function() {
    var totalNum = $('#total');
    var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
    var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
    var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
    var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
    var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
    var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
    var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
    var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

    if (pressed) {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked');
      var calories = $(this).data('calories');
      var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
      var fat = $(this).data('fat');
      +totalNum.html(currentCalories - calories);
      +totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs - carbs);
      +totalFats.html(currentFats - fat);
      +totalProteins.html(currentProteins - proteins);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      var calories = $(this).data('calories');
      var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
      var fat = $(this).data('fat');
      var proteins = $(this).data('fat');
      +totalNum.html(currentCalories + calories);
      +totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs + carbs);
      +totalFats.html(currentFats + fat);
      +totalProteins.html(currentProteins + fat);
    }

    var attr = $(this).attr('vegan');
    console.log(attr);
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
      $('#type').text("This is Vegan!")
      $('#typeImage').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
    } else {
      $('#type').text("This is not Vegan!")
      $('#typeImage').attr("src", "http://www.hellocurry.com/images/nonveg_icon.png");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>padthai wokbar calorie counter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logofinal.png" alt="padthai wokbar" style="width:300px;" />
    <h1>How did you build your bowl?</h1>
    <p>Select all the ingredients you added to your padthai wokbar meal and we'll do the rest.</p>
    <br />
    <div class="ingredients">
      <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">Bases</h2>
      <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" data-vegan="true" vegetarian>
         <p>Rice Noodles</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
         <p>Egg Noodles</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
         <p>Vermicelli</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
         <p>Whole Grain Noodle</p>
       </div>   

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
         <p>White Rice</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Brown Rice</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Vegetable Base</p>
       </div>

       <h2 style="color:#C84327;">Proteins</h2>
       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Chicken</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Pork</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Smoked Tofu</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Beef</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Duck</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Prawns</p>
       </div>

       <h2 style="color:#90A94D;">Toppings</h2>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Vegetable Mix</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Cashew</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Sweet Peppers Mix</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Wood Ear Mushroom</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Mushroom</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Pineapple</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Bamboo Shots</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Chinese Cabbage</p>
       </div>

       <h2 style="color:#424040;">Sauces</h2>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Thailand-Padthai</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Chinese Sweet and Sour</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Burma- Green Curry</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Indonesia- Satay</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Laosz- Red Curry</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Japan- Teriyaki</p>
       </div>

       <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">Extra Toppings</h2>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Roasted Peanut</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Coriander</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Sesame Seed</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
         <p>Basil</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegan>
         <p>Coconut Chips</p>
       </div>

       <h2 style="color:#C84327;">Desserts</h2>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="40" data-carbs="250">
         <p>Cumin Lemon Vinaigrette</p>
       </div>

       <div class="ingredient" data-calories="40" data-carbs="250">
         <p>Honey Cilantro Vinaigrette</p>
       </div>

       <div class="total">
         Total calories: <span id="total"></span> 
         Total Carbs:<span id="totalCarbs"></span>
         Total Fat:<span id="totalFats"></span>
         Total Protein:<span id="totalProteins"></span>

         <br>
         <img id="typeImage" src="" height="50" width="50" alt="Select Something!"/>
         <span id="type"></span>
         <img id="typeImagevega" src="" height="50" width="50" alt=""/>
         <span id="typevega"></span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
     <script  src="js/index.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

So here's my issue. I would like to create menu recommendations based on different diets ( paleo, vegan, vegetarian, ketogenic etc.)

Right now, I have 1 item with an attr. vegan (coconut chips), but the conditionals don't work the way I want them to. What I would like to achieve is to have the person click a 'non vegan' item, say chicken, and have the red icon pop up (so far so good), however if I click on coconut chips afterwards, it turns green... now that shouldn't happen ^^. If all clicked items have the 'vegan' attribute, the green button appears, otherwise red. If no items are clicked, the button dissappears.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you have an HTML/js/css question and sample code, please do make USE of the built in SO html/js/css snippet. It makes it easier to read, and especially to execute. Also what have you tried to solve your problem? SO is not a free coding service, first please try and attempt to solve the problem by yourself, when you are completely out of ideas then post on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/jhw4v5dd/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var vegan = true;
  $('.ingredient').click(function() {
    var totalNum = $('#total');
    var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
    var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
    var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
    var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
    var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
    var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
    var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
    var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

    if (pressed) {
      $(this).removeClass('clicked');
      var calories = $(this).data('calories');
      var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
      var fat = $(this).data('fat');
      +totalNum.html(currentCalories - calories);
      +totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs - carbs);
      +totalFats.html(currentFats - fat);
      +totalProteins.html(currentProteins - proteins);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      var calories = $(this).data('calories');
      var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
      var fat = $(this).data('fat');
      var proteins = $(this).data('fat');
      +totalNum.html(currentCalories + calories);
      +totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs + carbs);
      +totalFats.html(currentFats + fat);
      +totalProteins.html(currentProteins + fat);
    }

    var attr = $(this).attr('vegan');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
     if(vegan) {
       $('#type').text("This is Vegan!");
       $('#typeImage').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
      }
    } else {
      $('#type').text("This is not Vegan!");
      vegan = false;
      $('#typeImage').attr("src", "http://www.hellocurry.com/images/nonveg_icon.png");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <img src="http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logofinal.png" alt="padthai wokbar" style="width:300px;" />
  <h1>How did you build your bowl?</h1>
  <p>Select all the ingredients you added to your padthai wokbar meal and we'll do the rest.</p>
  <br />
  <div class="ingredients">
    <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">Bases</h2>
    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" data-vegan="true" vegetarian>
      <p>Rice Noodles</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
      <p>Egg Noodles</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
      <p>Vermicelli</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
      <p>Whole Grain Noodle</p>
    </div>   

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
      <p>White Rice</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Brown Rice</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Vegetable Base</p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="color:#C84327;">Proteins</h2>
    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Chicken</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Pork</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Smoked Tofu</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
    <p>Beef</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Duck</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Prawns</p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="color:#90A94D;">Toppings</h2>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Vegetable Mix</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Cashew</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Sweet Peppers Mix</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Wood Ear Mushroom</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Mushroom</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Pineapple</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Bamboo Shots</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Chinese Cabbage</p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="color:#424040;">Sauces</h2>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Thailand-Padthai</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Chinese Sweet and Sour</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Burma- Green Curry</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Indonesia- Satay</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Laosz- Red Curry</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Japan- Teriyaki</p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">Extra Toppings</h2>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Roasted Peanut</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Coriander</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Sesame Seed</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
      <p>Basil</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegan>
      <p>Coconut Chips</p>
    </div>

    <h2 style="color:#C84327;">Desserts</h2>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="40" data-carbs="250">
      <p>Cumin Lemon Vinaigrette</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ingredient" data-calories="40" data-carbs="250">
      <p>Honey Cilantro Vinaigrette</p>
    </div>

    <div class="total">
      Total calories: <span id="total"></span> 
      Total Carbs:<span id="totalCarbs"></span>
      Total Fat:<span id="totalFats"></span>
      Total Protein:<span id="totalProteins"></span>

      <br>
      <img id="typeImage" src="" height="50" width="50" alt="Select Something!"/>
      <span id="type"></span>
      <img id="typeImagevega" src="" height="50" width="50" alt=""/>
      <span id="typevega"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've created one variable named `vegan` and assigned value as `true`, still the time you don't click `non-veg`, the value remains true.

Once you click `non-veg` item then the value of the variable changes to false.

Changed code in `JavaScript`

```
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
  if(vegan) {
    $('#type').text("This is Vegan!");
    $('#typeImage').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
  }
} else {
  $('#type').text("This is not Vegan!");
  vegan = false;
  $('#typeImage').attr("src", "http://www.hellocurry.com/images/nonveg_icon.png");
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Shiladtya Thank you very much, that was it!

Comment: @Pbalazs89 Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think it will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.ingredient').click(function() {
   var totalNum = $('#total');
   var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
   var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
   var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
   var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
   var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
   var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
   var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
   var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

if (pressed) {
  $(this).removeClass('clicked');
  var calories = $(this).data('calories');
  var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
  var fat = $(this).data('fat');
  +totalNum.html(currentCalories - calories);
  +totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs - carbs);
  +totalFats.html(currentFats - fat);
  +totalProteins.html(currentProteins - proteins);
} else {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  var calories = $(this).data('calories');
  var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
  var fat = $(this).data('fat');
  var proteins = $(this).data('fat');
  +totalNum.html(currentCalories + calories);
  +totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs + carbs);
  +totalFats.html(currentFats + fat);
  +totalProteins.html(currentProteins + fat);
}

var vegan = false;
$(".ingredient.clicked").each(function(){
    if(typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined"){
    vegan = true;
  }
  else {
    vegan = false;
    return false;
  }
});


if(vegan) {
    $('#type').text("This is Vegan!");
    $('#typeImage').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
  }

  else {
  $('#type').text("This is not Vegan!");

  $('#typeImage').attr("src", "http://www.hellocurry.com/images/nonveg_icon.png");
}

});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!